# Placing additional text on an SSRS chart

Tags: text, reporting-services, charts, label

On an SSRS chart in design mode, I noticed that I can add titles and axis titles where you can type the title text using the title properties.

We would like to place some additional text on the chart that is not a title and not be restricted to the positioning of the text. We are trying to do something like when you place a text label on a web form or a Windows form, but on a SSRS chart instead.

The text will be used to further describe and explain the data that's on the chart.

If this can be done, please let us know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not something that I think can be achieved that easily with report services.

One way (depending on the chart you're using, and where you want your label), maybe to use the  chart data labels.

You can toggle visibility of each label based on an expression and padding the bottom of the text can be done with additional line breaks in the expression.

Here is a quick example chart I knocked up. Where I just show 1 label in either the top left or right corner of the graph.

[image: Chart1]
[image: Chart2]

If you're setting an expression as the data label then you need to set the `UseLabelAsValue` parameter to false.

---

As promised here is a few screenshots and description of the steps I took:

[image: Step 1]

I used a line graph for this example, but it should work in the same principle for any graph.

Right click on the series and show data labels

[image: Step 2]

In the parameter bar in the misc section change `UseLabelAsValue` to False. In the 'visible' parameter enter the following expression.

```
=(Last(Fields!label.Value,"Chart1")=Fields!label.Value)
```

("Chart1" is the data scope of the chart). That will return true for only the last data point. (You could use `First` if you wanted the label on the left of the graph)

`Position` can be set relative to the data point and also can be used with an expression. I've been using Top and TopRight for testing. This will allow you control of where the data label is placed.

`Label` is where you put what you want to be displayed. You can add line breaks using `VbCrLf`, and if you want to raise the label higher you can pad the text with additional line breaks.

I used

```
="This is a test" & VbCrLf & "Put text here" & VbCrLf & "Description"
```

[image: Step 3]

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. We wanted to put multiple labels on the chart which happens to be a "Line" chart. Seems the only label choice in that type of chart is "Title" and they only allow it to be placed under the previous title that was placed in the chart or on the bottom, left and right sides in a vertical orientation. It looks like they don't allow placing free-form labels on the charts. I hope they provide that in the near future.

Comment: Data labels are selected on the series. You should be able to use them on any chart type.

Comment: Hi Sam, I found a pop-up menu selection for turning on "data labels" on the series, but these are only showing the data numbers. We are hoping to place free-form labels anywhere we want if that is possible.

Comment: yes, as I put in my post you need to change `UseLabelAsValue` to false and add an expression. Click on the data labels, then view parameters in the bar on the right side of the screen. The two you need are at the bottom.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the report you did that you can send to us so we can see how you did it? Screen shots like in your post showing the steps taken would also be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't save the report unfortunately, but it only took me around 15 minutes to put together.. I'll try to post some more screenshots of the steps I took later tonight when I'm home and have a bit more time.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that I found that works for me is using Titles, but then use CustomPosition at the bottom of the Properties Pane.

[image: screenshot of the CustomPosition fields in Properties]

Comment: Upload the image directly to the post instead of linking to it, so there will be no dead links in the future!

Comment: The accepted answer is clever and probably invaluable in more complex situations, but this works and seems far preferable for users who simply want to place arbitrary text somewhere on the chart.

Comment: @Spoek The link is to SO's imgur subdomain, which is the same place images are stored if they are "uploaded directly to the post", i.e. displayed inline, so there's no difference in reliability... just readability. I think it's worth editing this to actually display the image rather than just linking to it.